# Using for-loops to replace a certain character

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, replace

The purpose of my code is to ask the user for a string, but the user has to use the number "2" to replace the word "to". Then, in my method useProperGrammar, the program should replace the number "2" for the word "to". The method returns the corrected sentence along with the number of errors fixed, which indicates the purpose of the variable counter. However, when I execute my code, the corrected code nor the number of grammar mistakes is displayed, what is the problem with my method? I know I can use the static method ".replace()", but I wanted to know if there were any other ways to solve this problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Grammar
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence (replace \"to\" for the number \"2\")");
    String begin = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(useProperGrammar(begin));
    }
    
    public static String useProperGrammar(String sentence)
    {
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<sentence.length(); i++)
    {
        String character = sentence.substring(i, i+1);
        if(character.equals("2"));
        {
            String front = sentence.substring(0, i);
            String back = sentence.substring(i+1);
            sentence = front + " to " + back;
            counter++;
        }
    }
        return sentence + "\nFixed " + counter + "grammatical errors:";
        
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are changing `sentence` then `sentence.length` will also be changed

Comment: If you are saying nothing at all is displayed, that would mean your application has crashed. Do you see a stack trace anywhere?

Comment: I created a new variable to return in the method so that `sentence` remains unaltered. However, I also had another error. The counter is returning the length of the string (6) instead of only returning how many "2"s were in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove the `;` after `if(character.equals("2"))`

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Grammar
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence (replace \"to\" for the number \"2\")");
    String begin = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(useProperGrammar(begin));
    }
    
    public static String useProperGrammar(String sentence)
    {
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<sentence.length(); i++)
    {
        String character = sentence.substring(i, i+1);
        if(character.equals("2"))
        {
            String front = sentence.substring(0, i);
            String back = sentence.substring(i+1);
            sentence = front + " to " + back;
            counter++;
        }
    }
        return sentence + "\nFixed " + counter + "grammatical errors:";
        
    }
}
```

Comment: What should I need to add in case that there are no "2"s in the user input?

Comment: Can you give an example of what output you are expecting when there are no "2"s

Comment: For example: the user inputs "This is a sentence", is there any way to output this sentence after executing the method?

Comment: We can use .contains method `if( ! sentence.contains("2"))  { return sentence; }`

Comment: One more thing, if there is more than one "2", the program will not replace all of them right?

Comment: The program will replace any number of "2"s so yes it will replace more than one "2". You could have run the program to test this yourself.

Comment: I just ran it but it only replaced the last "2" (input: 2 2 2 2; output: 2 2 2 to).

Comment: This test case worked fine on my machine.  [check this](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/aNmWSDIcnY) . Not sure why you are facing this issue.